# Excel/Macro/Email. How do I remove loop function from this VBA code & run each row individually?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

this is my first time asking a question here, would really appreciate how i could remove the loop and run the macro line by line manually?

```
Sub Email()
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMail As Object
   Dim olRecip As Object
   Dim iRow As Long
   Dim Recip As String
   Dim Subject As String


   iRow = 2

   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))

      Recip = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
      Subject = Cells(iRow, 3).Value


      Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

      With olMail
         Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
        .Display
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLbody = "<html><body><p>Dear " & Cells(iRow, 2).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "summary " & Cells(iRow, 3).Value & " summary" & Cells(iRow, 4).Value & "summary" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "summary" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "conclusion" & .HTMLbody
         olRecip.Resolve
        .Display

      End With

      iRow = iRow + 1

   Loop

   Set olApp = Nothing

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

comment your code

```
Sub Email() Dim olApp As Object Dim olMail As Object Dim olRecip As Object Dim iRow As Long Dim Recip As String Dim Subject As String

    iRow = 2

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'If column A has more the 1 email, will send/display email 1 at a time
    'Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))      

      Recip = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
      Subject = Cells(iRow, 3).Value


      Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

      With olMail
         Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
        .Display
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLbody = "<html><body><p>Dear " & Cells(iRow, 2).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "summary " & Cells(iRow, 3).Value & " summary" & Cells(iRow, 4).Value & "summary" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "summary" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "conclusion" & .HTMLbody
         olRecip.Resolve
        .Display

      End With

      iRow = iRow + 1

    'Msgbox to show email was sent or failed
    'Loop

    Set olApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    End Sub '
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to debug? I guess what you want to do is to press F8 to step into the code.